# Search in multidimensional array and return result without support variable

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have 2 array:

```
$fruits = array(
    'Apple' => array('id' => 1),
    'Banana' => array('id' => 2),
    'Peach' => array('id' => 3)
);
$carts = array(
    'Olivia' => array(51, 3, 2),
    'Harry' => array(312, 314, 10),
    'Charlie' => array(1, 314, 626)
);
```

I want to write something if some fruits id is in a cart. I have this code and it's work.

```
foreach ($carts as $cart) {
    $boughtFruit = false;
    foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
        if (in_array($fruit['id'], $cart)) {
            echo "Fruit <br>";
            $boughtFruit = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$boughtFruit){
        echo "No Fruit <br>";
    } 
}
```

return:

```
Fruit
No fruit
Fruit
```

I don't like my solution because i need to use a support variable `$boughtFruit` and 2 foreach.

Could you suggest me the same code using a `PHP` function (if it exists) and without`$boughtFruit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to inner loop, instead use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to finding same value in arrays.

```
$fru = array_column($fruits, "id");
foreach ($carts as $cart) {
    echo count(array_intersect($cart, $fru)) ? "Fruit <br>" : "No Fruit <br>";
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/h1Cb6)

---

Also if you want to get name of matched fruit, use this code

```
$fru = array_map(function($item){return $item['id'];}, $fruits);
foreach ($carts as $cart) {
    $find = array_intersect($cart, $fru);
    if (count($find)){
        $result = implode(", ", array_map(function($item) use($fru){
            return array_search($item, $fru);
        }, $find));
        echo "Fruit ({$result})\n";
    } else
        echo "No Fruit \n";
}
```

Output:

```
Fruit (Peach, Banana)
No Fruit 
Fruit (Apple)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/hpGEX)